# looking for a way to specify custom Regex Wild Cards from a Python List

Tags: python, regex

Excuse the title, I really have no idea how to properly word this question, but hopefully my description below shows what I am trying to do. I want to match sentences out of a large set of sentences (10,000) that have consecutive words from predetermined lists. I've used Regex in the past, but I don't know enough about it to know whether or not this is even practical in Regex.

I have two unique wild card lists, each contain about 20 total entries. The consecutive wild card patterns in the sentence could be as long as 8 words.

```
Fruit = List of 20 Fruits
Objects = List of 20 Objects
```

Find sentences that match in the following way:

```
* Fruit Object Fruit Object Fruit Object Fruit Object *
```

For Example:

```
Pineapple Stone Apple Rock Grape Club Blueberry Frisbee
```

Is this even possible to do in regex or would it be too impractical? In researching, the only Regex solution I have found would result in an absurdly long expression, which I can't even imagine how long that might take to compute.

In other words, is there some way to use custom wild cards in Regex that are specified by python lists? Preferably without having to repeat them multiple times for every occurrence in the regex expression.

Maybe there is a way to define them at the start of the Regex Expression, and then substitute them in for each occurrence within the expression?

Edit:
Need a way to be able to specify custom word order on a dynamic basis. Such as [F][O][O][O][F] or [F][F][O][F][O]. Ideally the template to search for would be fed into the Regex by the preceding python script.

Comment: This is not really a good application for regexes. What you'll want instead is something in the realm of [context-free grammar parsers](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Comment: I'll look into it @SebastianLenartowicz. I figured Regex might not be ideal, but in the past I have found Regex to be significantly faster at wildcard string matching than python based looping systems. If pyparsing avoids that, then that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, no problem:

```
^(?:\b(?:apple|banana|kiwi|morefruit)\s+(?:knife|spoon|fork|moreobjects)\s*){1,8}$
```

will match strings that contain one to eight fruit/object pairs, separated by spaces.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uba4I1/1).

**Explanation:**

```
^                                 # Start of string
(?:                               # Start of non-capturing group
 \b                               # Assert that we're at the start of a word
 (?:apple|banana|kiwi|morefruit)  # Match a fruit
 \s+                              # Match one or more spaces
 (?:knife|spoon|fork|moreobjects) # Match an object
 \s*                              # Match any number of spaces
){1,8}                            # Do this one to eight times
$                                 # Match the end of the string.
```

The reason for the `*` quantifier instead of `+`is that there might not be a trailing space at the end of the string. The `\b` [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) makes sure that there will be spaces between objects and fruits within the string, though.

If you need to specify other orders besides simple repetition of a pattern, you need to spell them out in the regex. But you can easily construct those parts of the regex, for example

```
In [1]: fruit = ["apple", "banana", "kiwi"]

In [2]: subregex = r"\b(?:" + "|".join(fruit) + r")\s*"

In [3]: print(subregex)
\b(?:apple|banana|kiwi)\s*
```

and construct your regex from those subregexes.

Comment: I should have specified more in the question. What if the list is more dynamic than just repeating Fruit/Objects. Such as Fruit Object Object Object Fruit, or Fruit Fruit Object Fruit Object, etc. I need a way to specific different word orders on a dynamic basis.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the regex is based on a pattern string. Simply assemble the string dynamically like any other string:

```
import re

FRUITS = 'apple pineapple strawberry'.split()
OBJECTS = 'shoe umbrella time-machine'.split()


# join the names on the pipe character and surround with parens
# Don't forget to use re.escape() to cancel out characters that have special meaning
def create_regex_part(names):
    part = '|'.join(re.escape(name) for name in names)
    return '({})'.format(part)


FRUIT_REGEX_PART = create_regex_part(FRUITS)
OBJECT_REGEX_PART = create_regex_part(OBJECTS)


# Combine the regex parts to one regex
def create_regex(template):
    with_spaces = '\s+'.join(template)
    content = with_spaces.replace('F', FRUIT_REGEX_PART).replace('O', OBJECT_REGEX_PART)
    return re.compile(content)


print(create_regex('FO').findall('apple shoe')) # [('apple', 'shoe')]
```

For extra flexibility, this can be done via a mapping from template letters to their possible values, which will ease adding new letters:

```
MAPPING = {
    'F': 'apple pineapple strawberry'.split()
    'O': 'shoe umbrella time-machine'.split()
}


def create_regex(mapping, template):
    parts = [create_regex_part(mapping[letter]) for letter in template]
    pattern = '\s+'.join(parts)
    return re.compile(pattern)


print(create_regex(MAPPING, 'FO').findall('apple shoe')) # [('apple', 'shoe')]
```